# flash/vector asset generation for other platforms like C#

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, resources, embedded-resource

The magic of Flash (and some claim the downfall) is the Flash IDE. The Flash IDE is pretty good at generating assets for my purposes. Essentially you draw or import whatever you like, then assign a class name. Export as swf, and load with another swf that knows what to look for.

The lack a graphical way of generating content/assets is a bit limiting for me. There is the possibility of generating a vector file per resource, but compared to the production pipeline in flash it's quite cumbersome.

Are there any libraries that can display and interact with swf embedded classes or alternative means of creating content for use in a different environment?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question; are you asking if there is an IDE to create graphics/assets for C# projects?

Comment: that, or a way to utilise the assets in C#

Comment: Hmm.. I haven't really got any experience with C# outside of XNA which just has a content loader thingy that you can target assets with pretty easily to create `Texture2D`s or whatever you need.

Comment: It has: `Texture2D zombieTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Zombie");` where `"Zombie"` is a string representing the asset name in the solution explorer.

Comment: This wouldn't allow me to generate more complex assets. I couldn't insert a graphic called button or a text field inside the class/asset

Comment: Unfortunately you have to build things like that yourself out of what tools you have. Make a `Button` class that accepts a graphic asset and a callback function for a click, etc.